# build.sh & CMakelists.txt

Tags: c++, gcc, build, compilation, g++

I'm a pretty novice in gcc compiler. I encountered with build infrastructure consisted of `build.sh` script and `CMakelists.txt` file. I'd like to understand what these files for and how to create simple project with `build.sh` & `CMakelists.txt` from scratch.

Comment: My guess is that there is also a README file nearby...

Comment: Actually, there isn't. Although `Changelog` file is :)